# Building a html list tree from SQL table using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, tree, hierarchy

I have this table:

```
+-------------------------------+
| NodeID | Parent | HasChildren |
+-------------------------------+
|1000000 |-1      |-1           |
+--------+--------+-------------+
|2409999 |1000000 |-1           |
+-------------------------------+
|2510921 |1000000 |-1           |
+-------------------------------+
|2596822 |2510921 |0            |
+-------------------------------+
|3000143 |2409999 |0            |
+-------------------------------+
|3125674 |2409999 |0            |
................................
       the list goes on
```

... from which I need to build a html tree list using `<ul>` and `<li>`. Every node in this table is a child of top node with id 1000000 (which has Parent "-1"). Also, HasChildren "-1" tells that this node has children, 0 - it has not. Yes, it's kinda weird convention, but it's as it is. So, the output should be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>2409999</li>
  <ul>
    <li>3000143</li>
    <li>3125674</li>
  </ul>
  <li>2510921</li>
  <ul>
    <li>2596822</li>
  </ul>
....
</ul>
```

Perhaps someone has tackled the very same problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the numbers in your example don't match the ones in the table. Can you make an example with the table as given?

Comment: this example is for illustration only. i really can't make an example with the table as it's got over 20k entries.

Comment: @Ghinzu, Bazzz meant that the example data you have included at the top of the question do not match the data in the example output at the end of you question. Please can you edit them so that they match?

Comment: @MarkBannister Bazzz, Made an example. Thanks for your input guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, it would make sense to use a nested set representation in your table. If you decide to keep the existing table structure, then the general way of doing it is to have a recursive function along the lines of:

```
function printBranch($parentID) {
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child is a Leaf) echo '<li>child</li>';
        elseif ($child is a Branch) printBranch($child);
    }
}
```

Needless to say the code above is pseudo-code, but it should demonstrate the general idea. The function executes on a single node, and if that node has children it calls *itself* on each of the children. That is called *recursion*. As a common programming convention: nodes that have children are called branches, and the ones that don't are called leafs.

Answer (score 0):

If your table layout is up for redesign, I'd use a left-right table layout, like the one listed in this article.

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/